# How to create dynamic lamda expression in linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to filter a list by adding where clause depends on if the property required in where clause is not null in input parameter then only add it in where clause otherwise don't add it. If both are not null then filter with both properties. Here in below example there are three if conditions, can we combine them together into one lamda expression?

```
 public class Employee
{
    public int? Property1 { get; set; }
    public int? Property2 { get; set; }

    public Employee GetEmployeeByProperty(Employee employee)
    {
        Employee filteredEmployee = new Employee();
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        // Logic to fill employee list

        #region Can we combine these conditions into one lamda expressoin
        if (employee.Property1 != null && employee.Property2 != null)
            filteredEmployee = employees.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Property1 == employee.Property1 && r.Property2 == employee.Property1);
        else if (employee.Property1 != null)
            filteredEmployee = employees.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Property1 == employee.Property1);
        else if (employee.Property2 != null)
            filteredEmployee = employees.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Property2 == employee.Property2); 
        #endregion

        return filteredEmployee;
    }
}
```

Any hint will help.

Comment: Used Func expression predicate and its much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.FirstOrDefault(lambda)`, build an expression like `.Where(lambda).FirstOrDefault()`;

```cs
        IEnumerable<Employee> employees = ...

        if (employee.Property1 != null)
            employees = employees.Where(r => r.Property1 == employee.Property1);
        if (employee.Property2 != null)
            employees = employees.Where(r => r.Property2 == employee.Property2); 

        filteredEmployee = employees.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are actually looking for, however

```
if (employee.Property1 != null || employee.Property2 != null)
    filteredEmployee = employees.FirstOrDefault(r => 
            (employee.Property1 == null || r.Property1 == employee.Property1) &&
            (employee.Property2 == null || r.Property2 == employee.Property2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Note that the case when both employee.Property1 and employee.Property2 are null is not handled.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int? Property1 { get; set; }
    public int? Property2 { get; set; }

    public Employee GetEmployeeByProperty(Employee employee)
    {
        Employee filteredEmployee = new Employee();
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        // Logic to fill employee list
        filteredEmployee = employees.FirstOrDefault(r => 
           (employee.Property1 == null || r.Property1 == employee.Property1) && 
           (employee.Property2 == null || r.Property2 == employee.Property1));

        return filteredEmployee;
    }
}
```